# Should an overweight person not do Running and skipping because it can hurt knee joints?

Tags: running, weight-loss

My weight is 115 Kg and I want to lose weight. Some people suggested that I do running and skipping and say running can hurt my knees because of my weight.

If running and skipping can hurt my knees, should I just do cycling?

Comment: Why don't you give running and skipping a try and see how your knee's feel afterwards? Self evaluate and go from there. If it hurts, stick with the cycling. Zero impact. Smooth gradient. Hope that helps, Mike

Comment: Consider this answer regarding the efficacy of aerobic vs strength training for fat loss. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117

Comment: Weight without height is meaningless, as is height without weight. 253 lbs at 6'6" is much different than 253 lbs at 5'6".

Comment: @JohnP My height is 5 foot 11 inch

Comment: Also consider these q/a: [Overweight running bad for your knees?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/115/is-running-while-overweight-bad-for-your-knees), [Walking to lose Weight](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2311/can-walking-be-a-way-to-lose-weight/2323#2323) for some alternatives and [Couch to 5K](http://www.c25k.com/podcasts.htm). To lose weight you need to also address your eating habits and nutrition.

Answer (score 4):

Please please don't let your weight put you off running, or any sport.  I ran when I was around your weight (I started at 148kg but didn't take up running til I'd lost some) and lost weight doing it.  This article shows me running a 10k race and as you can see I am not a stereotypical running size (if there is such a thing).

http://www.wirralglobe.co.uk/news/8484391.Wirral_runner_s_inspirational_battle_with_weight/

I joined a group and so had a leader who was able to guide me and make sure that I didn't overdo it while encouraging me at the same time. Check Run England or your local leisure centres to see if there's any beginners running groups near you.

I tried skipping and I did do it a few times but found it very difficult, more so out of bad coordination and balance than because of my weight/joints.

I have found variety in exercise has helped, so I tend to vary between cycling (either a long ride outdoors or an intense spinning class indoors), running, swimming etc.

I wouldn't be put off by weight or size to do any exercise as long as (as someone mentions earlier) you are 
a: using proper form, even with cycling its important to ensure that your seat and handles are at the right height.
b: working to your ability (not doing too much too quickly, not overdoing it) 
c: stop if you feel any joint pain 
d: warm up and do plenty of stretching afterwards
e: stay hydrated.

Good luck with whatever sport you decide to do :)

Comment: I should add that my answer is based purely on personal experience and observation of others around me.

Answer (score 2):

Cycling would indeed be a better option until you don't lose some extra useless load. Also, consider step aerobics which you can do at home.

By the way, running *with a proper form* and skipping *with skill* aren't as traumatic as they would be if done improperly (this would require a very long answer, but in a few words, that is: running by landing on your forefoot and not overstriding; thus using your muscles rather than your skeletal chain to absorb the shock, for what matters running; and skipping by jumping only one inch - 2/3 cm - off the ground.
But again, those are pretty advanced techniques and if you are a beginner as I suppose, stick with lower impact cardiovascular activities. This will help you shred junk fat from your body and reinforce your muscles somewhat. Then you'll have more option and variety to add.

Comment: Also, remember that losing so much fat is *mostly* a matter of proper nutrition.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let anyone tell you what you can't do. They key is to listen to your body, build up gradually, and create a routine. If necessary, alternate between different forms of exercise. I am almost the same weight/build as you and can run 10k. But I would not do that on two consecutive days.

Start easy, and don't get discouraged. It gets easier if you don't force it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i think your answer can be yes and can be no.

i remember on my very young days, i was playing basketball, after just a year my knees started tohurt very bad and made me to start physiotrapy. my overweigh was less than ten but as basketbal needed jumping very high and same activities it made my needs hur very bad.

running for a 148k person cant be first option. even walking in bad conditions makes you legs hurt.
your best option is just start walking but on flat ground. walking alot on unflat ground like mountain,ramp, uphills will certainly hurt your legs. even bycicle riding will hurt you legs in these places. after losing you weight more and you body was ready for more activity you can find a health and diet adviser and take good movements from him and maybe you can start slow running.
remember a good diet and body activity should be together. one of them with weak activity can result even worse weight too.